# Manipulate dictionary after deserializing json in C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

**Hello, I have the following Json:**

```
{
  "login": {
    "login1": {
      "password": "Password123",
      "username": "admin1"
    },
    "login2": {
      "password": "Password123",
      "username": "admin2"
    }
  }
}
```

**The Class1 that I use to deserialize the Json named LoginData:**

```
public class LoginTypes
{

    [JsonProperty("login")]
    public Dictionary<string, LoginData> LoginData { get; set; }
}

public class LoginData
{
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**And the Class 2 where I use the Json in a switch:**

```
private LoginData loginData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginData>(dataJsonMap.loginJsonPath);

public void InformLogin(LoginEnum.Login loginType)
{
    switch (loginType)
    {
        case LoginEnum.Login.login1:
            browser.FillIn(userNameFieldId).With(loginData[login1].username);
            browser.FillIn(passwordFieldId).With(loginData[login1].password);
            break;
     }
 }
```

But I keep receiving an error message. I can't acces the dictonary like that, there's a red underline at loginData[login1] in class2 saying that I cannot apply indexing to an expression of type LoginData and I can't find a way to do so. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error message are you getting and where exactly are you getting it?

Comment: What's the actual error message? From what you're showing, it looks like in `loginData[login1]username` (isn't there a period missing after the closing bracket, anyway?), you are attempting to access `loginData` (an instance of your `LoginData` class that doesn't have an indexer) with an indexer. I suspect not calling your item data type *and* your dictionary variable the same ("LoginData") would already help make your code a bit more transparent.

Comment: You are missing a period : loginData[login1].username and loginData[login1].password

Comment: Hello, sorry, the period was there, my problem is the [ ] that I use to access the dictionary, it's saying that I can't use that. Updated the code.

Comment: There's another typo, both properties for user name and password start with upper case in your example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to you have missed one curly break(belongs to `Login` property) at the end of JSON?

```
{
  "login": {
        "login1": {
          "password": "Password123",
          "username": "admin1"
        },
        "login2": {
          "password": "Password123",
          "username": "admin2"
        }
    } //one missing curly break
}
```

Also this Json valid for `LoginTypes`  not for `LoginData` object.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it's there, It's a much longer Json, I forgot when pasting it here. My problem is actually to access the Dictionary in Class 2.

Comment: @MarePereira: Your comment doesn't sound like this answer solves the issue. If so, please do not mark the answer as "accepted" (the green checkmark on the left), as that will signal to any later visitors that this is the answer that correctly solves the described problem.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper after Mare comment I also added `Also this Json valid for LoginTypes not for LoginData object.` I think that is why Mare accepted the answer.

Comment: Yep, that's why

Answer (score 0):

You should deserialize to `LoginTypes' and once you have an instance of that class then you can write some code like

`loginType.LoginData[loginType].Username`

You are currently deserializing to LoginData which does not have any dictionary. I don't think your example JSON would successfully deserialize as such right now.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not very clear to me. You're not deserializing a dictionary in your code.
Maybe this type of code will help you (but the Json will have to be different):

```
class LoginData
{
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

class OtherClassUsingYourTypes
{
    public OtherClassUsingYourTypes(string jsonData)
    {
        this.loginDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, LoginData>>(jsonData);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, LoginData> loginDictionary;

    public void FillLogin(string loginKey)
    {
        LoginData loginValues = loginDictionary[loginKey];
        browser.FillIn(userNameFieldId).With(loginValues.Username);
        browser.FillIn(passwordFieldId).With(loginValues.Password);
    }
}
```